CKeditor 5 Fid Issue
I have migrated from Drupal 7 to Drupal 10. Everything is wokring fine after the migration but noticed an fid issue in ckeditor body. But the image on the fron end renders but the issue is when you try edit the content
Any idea how to fix this?
 [[{"fid":"27921","view_mode":"preview","fields":{"format":"preview","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"Division Director Angela Knecht","field_file_image_title_text[und][0][value]":"Division Director Angela Knecht"},"type":"media","field_deltas":{"2":{"format":"preview","field_file_image_alt_text[und][0][value]":"Division Director Angela Knecht","field_file_image_title_text[und][0][value]":"Division Director Angela Knecht"}},"attributes":{"alt":"Division Director Angela Knecht","title":"Division Director Angela Knecht","style":"height: 160px; width: 160px; margin: 0px 5px; float: left; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;","class":"media-element file-preview","data-delta":"2"}}]]
Tried with entity embed modules but no luck so far.
